# Spring 3 with Drools 6 maven inconcistency

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, drools

I have a problem integrating Drools with Spring. I am trying to make a simple Hello World spring example, I reached a moment where my simple project refuses to compile.
To work with Drools annotations like @KSession I need the drools-spring package, but it seems incompatible with Spring 3. As builder I use Maven. Here is how my .pom's looks like:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Drools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-spring</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Beta2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I use very simple case of controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class BaseController extends AbstractController {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BaseController.class);

    @Autowired
    @KSession("ksession-rules")
    KieSession mySession;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public @ResponseBody
    String test() {
        Fact myFact = new Fact();
        myFact.setFactNumber(20); //According to my rule when myFact.number>20 
                                  //then result will be set to "Hello World"

        mySession.insert(myFact);
        mySession.fireAllRules();

    return myFact.getResult();
    }
}
```

At this point I receive an error:
"The hierarchy of the type BaseController is inconsistent".
I noticed that if I remove drools-spring from the dependency list the project compiles successfully. However without that package I cannot deploy my project, because the deployer demands the drools' class responsible for interpreting @KSession and that class is located in drools-spring package.

After some investigation it appears that my Drools session configuration seems to have
nothing to do with the error above, so for the sake of succinctness I will not quote them. Instead of that I will mark that even if I don't make any modifications to the spring configuration and remove the KieSession from my example, making it a simple spring hello world example, I receive one and the same error out of my IDE (Eclipse): "The hierarchy of the type BaseController is inconsistent" and if I remove the drools-spring dependency the problem disappears.

It seems to me as dependency conflict.
Does anyone experienced similar problems with drools+spring?
Can someone suggest a solution to the problem?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try drools-spring dependency with <version>5.6.0.Final</version> instead of beta and then refresh/clean your project to build it again.

Comment: At Prasad - The reason why I am using the beta package is that I am using drools 6 and messing some packages from drools 5 and drools 6 may lead to one hell of a mess :). However I tried what you have suggested and the result is exactly the same. Without 5.6.0.Final package it is compiling, but with it, it fails to compile. However one of the reasons that I need drools-spring is to work with @KSession annotation and I believe that annotation is drools 6 specific, so I have no choise but to workwith the beta.

Comment: Not sure exactly what is imported by that version, but I would recommend checking the Spring dependencies which are imported by drools-spring and exclude them all in your pom.xml. Otherwise, they will almost certainly conflict with the Spring version you are using. Personally I prefer to integrate Drools and Spring without using the drools-spring library.

Comment: @Steve by integrating Drools with Spring without using drools-spring library you mean that you are not using spring dependency injection and the kmodule spring configuration, but manually instanciating your KieSession and use it though your Spring controllers??

Comment: I am of using Spring dependency injection. I just don't use drools-spring. I just create my own wrapper @Service instances where I use the API to create my knowledge base and associated sessions.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found two things.

Drools' drools-spring package declares its own spring dependencies that are overriding my spring dependencies, which leads to spring malunctions. What I did is to manually remove the spring dependencies from drools-spring .pom file.
Another mistake that I had in the upper example is that I didn't have kie-spring as dependency. Kie-spring is mandatory for one drools bean KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor, which is responsible to read my kmodule-kbase-ksession configuration from the spring configuration.

After resolving these two problems my project compiles now and I can see in the code that KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor defines that my configuration is being read and analized as I expected it to be.